# unable to connect to mysql from dataset designer

Tags: .net, mysql, dataset, database-connection, typed

I want to create a typed dataset which gets data from mysql. I have done this before using sqlserver 2005. But i have a big problem in connecting to MYSQL.

In the first step after adding Table Adapter, I need to select a connection string.
But mysqlconnectionstring which is in the webconfig does not appear in the select list.
So I clicked on "New connection".
and selected Data Source="Microsoft ODBC Data Source". Then I selected the radio button "use connection string". After entering the data, during "Test Connection" I am getting an error.

ERROR[IM002][Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

My Connection string "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1.7 Driver};server=100.100.100.xx;database=MyDB;uid=myUID" .

Please advice me. It has been frustrating for 2 days

Thanks a lot